# Stealing my information back

Tags: sybase, database-backups, database-restore, advantage-database-server, sqlanywhere

*TL;DR:*  My POS uses Sybase Advantage Database Server to store my sales data, and I'd like to access it, but I only have the backup files.

---

I own a small business with "advanced" POS software, which has the only copy of all my sales data ever. They have some backup scheme, but they're unwilling to divulge any details. There's also an automatic daily local backup routine, but because this is a POS and there are certain laws about deleting data, I am not allowed (nor do I have the software required) to restore from backup even to check that it works. I asked the support guy when the last time he had to restore from backup was, and he said "don't worry, we don't ever need it".

Naturally, I'm worried.

I'll note at this point that I am required by law to keep this data, and should I fail to do so for any reason I may personally face massive fines in the range of multiple millions. I'd like to avoid that.

Additionally to keeping the data, and verifying that the backups contain the data I so need to keep, I'd also like to create reports. The POS vendor claims that it can create any report I'd ever need, but every single time I've asked them about a report it either contained wrong data, crashed, exported unreadable files (to which their reply was that the files are fine, my [insert relevant file reader] is broken), or simply didn't exist (to which their reply is usually something like "you don't need that report anyway"). I asked about accessing a copy of the database myself, and they said they can't allow that. My only recourse is to pay them tens of thousands for developing and testing the report. What report do I want, you ask?

```
SELECT * FROM SALES
```

To create this simple report, I need to migrate my data from the Sybase Advantage Database Server backup files into a format I can use, e.g. a MySQL database, but all the migration tools I've found require access to a working database server.

How can I get my data out of these backups?

Comment: Advantage (ADS) supports multiple data formats (including their own proprietary format), most of which offer both table and row level encryption of data. They also have a data dictionary that, for certain data formats, enforces user rights and access to the data. What extension do your database files use (.ADT, .DBF)? Is there an .ADD file (which would be the data dictionary)?

Comment: Also, ADS works fine with the Advantage Local Server (ALS), which is a stand-alone local client DLL. You can get it free from the [ADS downloads page](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20), along with their equivalent of Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS); the ADS application is Advantage Data Architect (for some reason called ARC32), and it's also free. (If you're not sure what version of ADS is being used, download the most recent; they remain pretty well backwardly compatible.) ARC32 comes with the ALS files and installs them.

Comment: There is also a possibility to backup a database with `sp_BackupDatabase` and free tables with `sp_BackupFreeTables`. These backups can be restored with the corresponding `sp_Restore*` stored procedures. http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_online_backup.htm

Comment: The files I have are a `.db` and a `.log` file. I didn't realize ADS had a free version (their download page made it seem like only a trial), I'll try to use `sp_RestoreDatabase` using that. Thanks.

Comment: One `.db` and one `.log` doesn't sound like a native Advantage Database format. There are tools that can check what a file is based on it's contents. http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/File_Format_Identification

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff: I should have known the vendor wouldn't know what database they're using. Unfortunately the tools I've tried all report unuseful things like `file.db: data; file.log: data`. This dump of the file makes it seem to me like it is _some_ Sybase file, but I have no idea which - do you know what it could be? http://goo.gl/joplMe

Comment: Well there is a version 9.0.2 of Sybase `iAnywhere` that was released about a decade ago. I don't know anything about `iAnywhere` though ...

Comment: It's using a `.db` and a `.log` file: http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1001/en/dbdaen10/da-overview-dbfiles.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a complete Sybase `iAnywhere` database (which uses `.db` for the data and `.log` for the transaction log).

So you should be looking for `Sybase iAnywhere` or `Sybase SQLAnywhere` drivers and tools.

SAP / Sybase has a developer website here: http://scn.sap.com/community/sql-anywhere

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the detective work! I _never_ would have found that myself.

Comment: I fixed it to point to the SAP community page for SQL Anywhere.